# Неправильный результат

Tags: javascript

Функция parseInt("ASD", 15); - выдает результат 10.
Разве это верно?

Answer (score 2):

Это верно.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point.
>
> Если parseInt встречает символ, который не является цифрой в указанной
>   системе счисления, функция игнорирует его и все последующие символы
>   ...

В Вашем случае преобразование останавливается после цифры `A`.

```js
console.log(parseInt("ASD", 15));
console.log(Number("0xA"), Number("0xASD"));
console.log(+"0xA", +"0xASD");
```

Comment: Думается, автор ожидал, что А в 15-ной системе счисления будет 11, например. Однако что по основанию 11, 12, 13, 28, 36... все равно цифры закончатся на 9 и дальше будут буквы, начиная с А. `console.log(parseInt("ASD", 29)); // 9235` Впрочем начиная с основания 29 символ S уже будет учитываться.